# what does `private[akka]` syntax mean in Scala

Tags: scala

what does `[akka]` mean in `private[akka] object Mailbox`? The only thing similar I know of in Scala is type class but I have usually seen `[]` after class name eg `class SomeClas[] {???}`.

Comment: this is **qualified modifier**: https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/05-classes-and-objects.html#private

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This means that object MailBox can be seen by all classes under the 'akka' package level